# C++ wrapper class that is derived from an abstract base class and calls a method in another class that is also derived from the abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, wrapper

I have an abstract class called `Animal` and a derived class called `cow`.

`Cow` provides definitions of the pure virtual functions in `Animal`.

I want to create a class called `AnimalWrapper` that inherites from `Animal`. I want the method `AnimalWrapper.speak()` to simply call `cow.speak()`.

Do I just need a reference to a `cow` object in the animalwrapper class so that I can call the non static method speak?

How would I do this?

```
     #include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>

using namespace std;

#include <string>
class Animal // This Animal is an abstract base class
{

public:
    Animal(){};

    virtual const char* speak() = 0; //pure virtual function
};

class Cow: public Animal
{
public:
    Cow(){};

    virtual const char* speak() {
        cout << "I am a cow" << endl;
        return "Moo     ";
    }
};

class AnimalWrapper: public Animal
{
public:
    AnimalWrapper(){}

    virtual const char* speak() {

        cout << "Calling cow class speak() method" << endl;
        //Call Cow::speak()

        return "Moo";
    }
};


int main()
{
    AnimalWrapper AnimalWrapper_obj ;
    std::cout << AnimalWrapper_obj.speak() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What prevents you from deriving `CowWrapper` from `Cow` instead of `Animal`? In that case you can literally call `Cow::speak()` from within `CowWrapper` (or just not override it at all)...

Comment: I'm mostly curios about *why* you need the wrapper? What problem is it designed to solve?

Comment: As for your problem, if you want to call a non-static member function on an object, you need an instance of that object. Perhaps the wrapper-class should contain an instance of the wrapped object through composition (otherwise it isn't much of a *wrapper* now is it? ;) )

Comment: You have a CowWrapper which is an animal, but it's not a Cow. You don't have any Cows in your code. Which Cow should speak()? You can create a new cow in `CowWrapper::speak() { return cow().speak(); }`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude my apologies I have updated the question to reflect my uncertainty.

Comment: Your request is coming very close to common design patterns like Adapter, Bridge, and particularly Abstract Factory( i.e later you might want not only cows but others to speak as well).

Comment: You can direclty call `Cow::speak()` if it is declared as a static member fuction. Otherwise you need an instance of a `Cow`. I wonder if perhaps using template and template specialization would suit your problem better than using polymorphism

Comment: @Clonk thanks, so I think that the wrapper class should store a reference to the `cow` object so that it can call the `cow.speak()` method. Would you agree?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. So far I feel like you're presenting an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). Storing a reference of an instance of cow can work, though since you did not presented the problem you're trying to solve I'm not sure it is an approriate solution.

Comment: @Clonk I understand, sorry I don't want to waste anybodies time. I'm confident that storing a reference of an instance is what I need. If I can get that working on this example then I would know better, could you perhaps show me this if it is not too much trouble?

Comment: It would be faster to express directly your problem. Do you want AnimalWrapper to create an instance of Cow, have areference to an external Cow object or to take ownership of an existing instance of Cow (extending its lifetime) ?

Comment: @Clonk it a complicated C++ project with a large code base that I've inherited and don't know how to present it in a way that you could understand here i.e. code samples etc. Could you show me how `AnimalWrapper` can  have a reference to an external Cow object? This would help me proceed on my own. Thank you.

Comment: But why don't you just use the the classes of the project directly?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment here is an example of a class AnimalWrapper taking an external reference of a Cow instance using move semantic. Since it is a move constructor and not a copy constructor you should be careful when using your original object.

If you want to keep your original instance of Cow, then you might need a copy constructor instead (but you will duplicate your Cow instance).

You could also store a pointer or a reference in a class `Cow * cowInstance`or `Cow& cowInstance`) but you risk ending up with a dangling pointers / reference (hence why I used move semantics here).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include <memory>
// using namespace std; // <= Using namespace std is considered bad practice

#include <string>
class Animal // This Animal is an abstract base class
{

public:
    Animal(){}
    virtual ~Animal() {} // Do some research about the difference between virtual and non virtual destructor in C++
    virtual std::string speak() = 0; //pure virtual function
};

class Cow: public Animal
{
public:
    Cow(){}
    Cow(const Cow& cow) = delete;
    Cow(Cow&& _cow) {std::cout << "Move constructor " << std::endl;}
    virtual ~Cow() {}
    // virtual const char* speak() { // <= Use std::string in c++
    virtual std::string speak() {
        ++m;
        std::cout << "I am a cow : "<< m << std::endl;
        return std::string("Mooo");
    }

private: 
    int m = 0;
};

class AnimalWrapper // : public Animal // <= This is unnecessary
{
public:

    AnimalWrapper(std::unique_ptr<Cow> _cow) : cowInstance((std::move(_cow))) { 
    }

    std::string speak() {
        std::cout << "Calling cow class speak() method" << std::endl;
        return cowInstance->speak();
    }
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Cow> cowInstance;
};


int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Cow> cow(new Cow);
    cow->speak();
    std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;
    AnimalWrapper AnimalWrapper_obj(std::move(cow));
    std::cout << AnimalWrapper_obj.speak() << '\n';
}
```

Since the problem you are trying to solve is still unclear to me, this is probably not an ideal / perfect solution. Nonetheless, it is an example of what you asked according to my understanding.

Comment: thank you for your kind explanation. This is what I looking to understand. Move semantic is a little too advanced for me although I sort of understand what you doing. Would it be too much to ask to see the same example in which you store a reference in the class. What I am trying to understand is you would call a the `speak()` method on the stored `Cow& cowInstance` in the `AnimalWrapper` class. Then I will progress to move semantic. Thank you

Comment: The problem with storing a reference is that you either store a reference to an external `Cow` object which you do not control the lifetime and you risk having your program crash by having a dangling reference (reference to a deleted object). Or you have to copy the `Cow`object but you then have 2 separate and independant instance of `Cow`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to extend the API in use, but cannot modify it itself, I conclude that you want to provide a parallel hierarchy:

```
namespace wrapped
{
class Animal
{
public:
    virtual ~Animal();
    virtual std::string speak();
};

class Cow : public Animal
{
public:
    std::string speak() override;
    unsigned int giveMilk() { return 77; }
};
}

namespace wrapping
{
class Animal
{
protected:
    wrapped::Animal& animal;
    Animal(wrapped::Animal& animal)
        : animal(animal)
    { }
public:
    virtual ~Animal() { }

    // does not need to be virtual, we can profit from
    // polymorphism of referred object...
    //
    // still it CAN be virtual, if you want to allow derived
    // wrappers as well to modify the inherited speak!
    std::string speak()
    {
        return animal.speak();
    }
};

class Cow : public Animal
{
public:
    Cow(wrapped::Cow& cow)
        : Animal(cow)
    { }

    // speak is inherited

    unsigned int giveMilk()
    {
        // don't need dynamic cast as we passed a reference
        // to cow object to base class constructor...
        return static_cast<wrapped::Cow&>(animal).giveMilk();
    }
};
}
```

A variant you can use if `Cow` inherits *virtually* from `Animal` allows you to write a little less of code:

```
namespace wrapping
{
class Animal : private virtual wrapped::Animal
{
public:
    using wrapped::Animal::speak;
};

class Cow : public Animal, private wrapped::Cow
{
public:
    using wrapped::Cow::speak;
};
}
```

If `Cow` does not inherit virtually, though, your wrapping `Cow` would inherit two instances of `wrapped::Animal` which would lead to a number of problems not being discussed here for now.

If you override `speak` in `wrapping::animal`, though, you need to provide a *final overrider* in `wrapping::Cow` to resolve the ambiguity between both inherited overridden variants of `speak`.

Actually, you *could* inherit from the wrapped bases publicly, then you wouldn't need the using declarations any more (final overrider issue remains, though), but that would allow for a wild mixture between wrapped and wrapping classes, which you'd most likely want to prevent.

Comment: Truth, there was a typo in (CowWrapper instead of Cow for constructor name, additionally, `wrapping` namespaces had not been closed). Actually, you should have spotted easily yourself by examining compiler's error messages. Learning to understand these will safe you much trouble in the future and likely quite some questions here on SO...